# Open Validator error in SQL when there should not be?

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I'm getting an open validator error in the below sql code in bigquery for the count in 3:3. Can't figure out why though. Any pointers?

```
SELECT
  EXTRACT(hour FROM starttime) AS start_hour
  COUNT(*) as total_number_of_trips
FROM
  `bigquery-public-data.new_york_citibike.citibike_trips`
WHERE
  starttime IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY
  hour
ORDER BY
  hour
```

Comment: 1) A comma in output columns list is lost. 2) Does `bigquery-public-data.new_york_citibike.citibike_trips` is a name of a table?

Comment: Ugh. Yes. Missed the pesky comma. Thank you so much. Yes **bigquery-public-data.new_york_citibike.citibike_trips** is the name of the dataset.